# Cannot define a property called `wait` in Scala case class

Tags: scala

I am trying to define a property `wait` in a `case` `class`, however, it keeps giving me an error:

> overriding method wait in class Object of type ()Unit;
>   [error]  value wait cannot override final member
>   [error]       final case class Foo(wait: Bar)

```
final case class Foo(wait: Bar)
```

It looks like `wait` is a method in a base class somehow even though my case class did not inherit from anything. Is there a way to still define a class variable called `wait` though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, **Scala compiler** cannot handle this when **public field name** are same as [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)'s methods:

- notify
- notifyAll
- wait

Since When **Scala compiler** meet the public field, it will generate the default **getter**,  for your example, it will generate:

```
  public java.lang.String wait()
```

This will cause **name clash** issue with [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s wait method. but seems for now **Compiler** can't handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Your class inherits from `AnyRef`/`Object` implicitly, as every reference type needs to be a subtype of `AnyRef`. You can escape that by defining `Foo extends AnyVal`, but you *really* don't want to do that unless you know [what it means](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), as your class is no longer a normal class. Just name your method something else.

`wait` is a concurrency primitive. It's in `AnyRef` simply because Java decided to put it in `Object` (that is, blame Java, not Scala). When invoked inside a `synchronized` block, the calling thread goes to sleep until it is woken by some other thread calling `notify`(`All`) on the same object.